# Scaling OpenCV Mat for Caffe

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I've been following the [Caffe MINST example](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/mnist.html) and trying to deploy a test of the trained model with C++ where I use OpenCV to read in the images. In the example, they mention how for the training and test images they

> scale the incoming pixels so that they are in the range [0,1). Why
>   0.00390625? It is 1 divided by 256.

I've heard how there's a DataTransformer class in Caffe you can use to scale your images, but if I multiplied each pixel in the OpenCV Mat object by 0.00390625 would this give the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is right. But remember to convert your OpenCV Mats to float or double type before scaling.

Something like:

```
cv::Mat mat; // assume this is one of your images (grayscale)

/* convert it to float */
mat.convertTo(mat, CV_32FC1); // use CV_32FC3 for color images

/* scaling here */
mat = mat * 0.00390625;
```

---

**Update #1**: Converting and scaling can also simply be done in one line, i.e.

```
cv::Mat mat; // assume this is one of your images (grayscale)

/* convert and scale here */
mat.convertTo(mat, CV_32FC1, 0.00390625);
```

Comment: Thanks! Also good idea about the conversion to avoid any truncation!